# Android Clicking on items in listView Color should be changed?

Tags: android

I am having a small problem with the list-view? If the item is selected in the listview that row  color should be changed?

Comment: you can't demand here. Read StackOverflow FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);        

    }
```

Comment: sry i need through selectors. if the item is selected means it should be gray else the color should be transparent

Comment: @gujjulanikhilreddy If it works, mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark to the left. You'll get some reputation in return!

Answer (score 0):

set itemclicklistener for the list.Then in onitemclicklistener set the color for the view

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

}
```

visit this site
 http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
and scroll to Single vrs. Multiselection
It uses checkbox in listview .Follow similar process to set background color when selected and 
when  not selected